# Prototype Design Pattern vs ICloneable

Tags: c#, design-patterns, prototype-pattern

I am learning Design Patterns. Today I'm reading about **Prototype DP** and found that it's used for cloning an object. Since we have an **ICloneable interface** in .Net, do we still need the Prototype DP ? Or does `ICloneable` implement the Prototype DP? Any guidelines for choosing between the two ?

Comment: Don't implement the ICloneable interface: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/03/125427.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By implementing just an interface like `ICloneable` doesn't mean you're following a pattern, all depends in the intent you're trying to achieve. This is somewhat philosophical if you will, but I just want to be sure to stress this. Patterns have forces and intents, and by definition is a general solution for a common problem.

In this particular example, yes, implementing *correctly* the interface can lead you to the intent of the pattern, in fact the wikipedia article uses the `ICloneable` interface for its exameple written in Java : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern.
Of course you can use another approach, using another interface of yours, is not a requirement for the pattern to use the `ICloneable` interface.

Hope this helps and welcome to the world of patterns :)

Answer (score 4):

Design patterns are not something that are inherent in a language, but they are a common  solution to a general problem.  They are a concept and can be implemented in many different ways and many different languages.

Comment: That's actually not true. Design patterns are 'crutches' for missing functionality in the language. So with a good programming language you would inherit some or most of the patterns. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Criticism